# Why does figure close immediately after opening? And how to fix it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, figure, pandapower

I am having problem with a figure which closes immediatly after opening, so I can't see it.

I am programming in Python, using VS Code (cmd inside as the terminal) and using PandaPower library. I don't realize if the problem is in the coding, the vs code environment or something else?

I am following this tutorial: (scroll down to "Show tripped grid")
https://github.com/e2nIEE/pandapower/blob/develop/tutorials/protection/oc_relay.ipynb

If I run this exact same code in my computer this problem happens.

Here is the code I am currently working on, with the same problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandapower as pp
from pandapower.protection import oc_relay_model as oc_protection
from pandapower.protection.utility_functions import plot_tripped_grid
import random
from random import randint

def create_network():

def random_fault():

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create our testnetwork
    testnet = create_network()

    # run powerflow
    pp.runpp(testnet, init = 'flat')

    # get the location of the fault
    linefault, faultloc = random_fault()

    # create overcurrent protection (Definite Time OC protection)
    relay_settings_DTOC = oc_protection.oc_parameters(testnet, relay_type='DTOC', time_settings = [0.07, 0.5, 0.3])

    # trip a random line
    trip_decisions, testnet_sc = oc_protection.run_fault_scenario_oc(testnet,sc_line_id = linefault, sc_location = faultloc, relay_settings = relay_settings_DTOC)

    # !! THIS IS WHERE THE FIGURE IS DRAWN
    plot_tripped_grid(testnet_sc, trip_decisions, sc_location = faultloc, plot_annotations = True)
```

Comment: Your sample code doesn't demonstrate the problem. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.